# Remove chapter level indentation from minitoc within chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

It seems to me that there is an imbalance (in the distribution of ink) on a minitoc which is placed within a chapter; the `minitoc` appears to be somewhat shifted to the right.  I suspect that this is chapter level indentation.  I would like to remove chapter level indentation from the `minitoc` content called within a chapter.